# Why PHP does not escape single quote string but reserve the forward slash?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Are there any reason why forward slash need to be printed via `\\` even with single quoted string?

e.g.

```
php -r "print '\n';" # echo \n
```

Since single quotea string does not handle escape characters, so why the following statement is not valid?

```
php -r "print '\n\';"

Parse error: parse error in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: But it does. The slash is used to escape `'`

Comment: To prevent confusion with future questsions: *Forward Slash:* `/`, *Backward Slash (aka backslash)*: `\'`

Answer (score 2):

Well, no variable substitution and no escaping is done for strings in single-quotes with the exception for escaped single quotes within a single quoted string to allow you to insert a single quote into your string without having to use a double-quoted string for that special case.

Therefore your example will properly escape the string-terminating single quote, resulting in an unterminated string, causing the parse error.

So to print a backslash in front of a single quote within a single-quoted string, you'll have to escape the backslash itself. The single quote and the backslash in front of a single quote are the only characters you have to escape within a single-quoted string. All other characters will not get their special meaning applied if you use an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

For single quotes, `\'` represents a literal single quote.  Thus, your string is never closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web server installed on your computer the script you want to run is
`

echo "\n";

?>`

in order to print a newline character